# Fastest way to execute a many-to-many regex search?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have two lists of strings, both of which are quite long. I want to perform regex matching between the lists, using the first list as the matcher pattern and the second list as the target.

Example:

```
Index    List1    List2
  0      'abc'    '123456'
  1      '123'    'abcdefgh'
  2      'val'    'down to the valley'
```

My output should convey the following information in some form or another:

```
Index 0 of List1 matches with Index 1 of List2
Index 1 of List1 matches with Index 0 of List2
Index 2 of List1 matches with Index 2 of List2
```

What existing technologies/libraries are there for a simplistic matching like this in the JVM world? OpenNLP seems like overkill for something this simple. I am also not opposed to using my own implementation if there is an existing algorithm which is tried and true.

Comment: Can an element of list 1 match several elements in list 2?

Comment: yes, that would be fine if several matches exist

Comment: Might be interesting: https://www.arl.wustl.edu/~pcrowley/algorithmstoaccelerate.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you would consider?

```
val list1 = List("abc", "123", "val").zipWithIndex
val list2 = List("123456", "abcdefgh", "down to the valley").zipWithIndex

val result = list1.map {
  case (elmt1, i1) => {
    val matching = list2.filter {
      case (elmt2, i2) => elmt2.contains(elmt1)
    }
    "Index " + i1 + " of List1 matches with Index " +
      matching.map(_._2).mkString(", ") + " of List2"
  }
}

println(result)
```

It's a naive loop in O(n*m) where n and m are the lists sizes.

This would need handling of side cases when there is no match for an element of list 1 (currentlly it would `print Index 1 of List1 matches with Index  of List2`).

Comment: This is something like the naive solution I had envisioned. I was hoping there was a library or pre-existing algorithm that could achieve faster performance than O(n*m), perhaps by using some indexing or a sorting mechanism. However this may not exist or even be possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
val la = Array("abc", "123", "val")
val lb = Array("123456", "abcdefgh","down to the valley")

for {
  xa <- la.indices
  xb <- lb.indices
  if lb(xb).contains(la(xa))
} yield s"index $xa of A matches index $xb of B"
//res0: IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(index 0 of A matches index 1 of B,
//                                  index 1 of A matches index 0 of B,
//                                  index 2 of A matches index 2 of B)
```

Indexing a `List` is rather inefficient. `Array`s are better for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless copy from jwvh:

```
val la = Array("abc", "123", "val")
val lb = Array("123456", "abcdefgh","down to the valley")
```

own preference:

```
la.foreach (a => lb.foreach {b => if (b.matches (s".*$a.*")) println (s"match $a:$b")})
match abc:abcdefgh
match 123:123456
match val:down to the valley
```

For bigger data collections, you might try **.par**, which transforms the whole line into a parallel pipeline. If you have much data, do some measurements and call back on us. :)

```
la.par.foreach (a => lb.foreach {b => if (b.matches (s".*$a.*")) println (s"match $a:$b")})
```